# php - adding wildcards to anagram solver

Tags: php, anagram

I am sorry if I can't even provide what I have tried because I can't even figure out where to start.

I have this anagram solver which works great, the problem is that I want to be able to add the ability to allow the user to include a ? as a wildcard into the field.

For instance lets say the user puts in their letters fjsiem?. Obviously the ? means any letter. So the results will show words that match the letters in the field plus any other word that contains any additional letter.

I also would love to be able to point out the wildcard(letter) in every one of the words that contain the wildcard so I can change its color so the user knows which words have the wildcards.

Is there anyone who can take a look at my code and help me out?

The word file being called is combined.txt which simply contains words in every new line.

```
            <?
            if(!empty($_POST['l'])) {
                $time_start = microtime(true);
                $l = $_POST['l'];
                $l = strtolower($l);
                $len = strlen($l);

                $a = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 1, 'c' => 1, 'd' => 1, 'e' => 1, 'f' => 1, 'g' => 1, 'h' => 1, 'i' => 1, 'j' => 1, 'k' => 1, 'l' => 1, 'm' => 1, 'n' => 1, 'o' => 1, 'p' => 1, 'q' => 1, 'r' => 1, 's' => 1, 't' => 1, 'u' => 1, 'v' => 1, 'w' => 1, 'x' => 1, 'y' => 1, 'z' => 1);

                function contains($word) {
                    $wlen = strlen($word);
                    if($wlen < 2 || $wlen > 10) return FALSE;

                    for($i = 0; $i < $wlen; $i++) {
                        $w[$i] = $word[$i];
                    }

                    $b = $GLOBALS['b'];    
                    foreach($b as $n => $c) {
                        foreach($w as $k => $v) {
                            if($v == $c) {
                                unset($w[$k]);
                                unset($b[$n]);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if(count($w) > 0) return FALSE;
                    return TRUE;
                }


                for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
                    $b[$i] = $l[$i];
                    unset($a[$l[$i]]);
                }

                $e = 'cat combined.txt';
                while(list($k) = each($a)) {
                    if(!$e) {
                        $e = "grep -v $k combined.txt";
                    } else {
                        $e .= ' | grep -v '. $k;
                    }
                }

                exec($e, $o);

                settype($w, 'array');
                foreach($o as $v) {
                    if(contains($v)) {
                        $w[] = $v;
                    }
                }

                function mycmp($a, $b) {
                    $ca = strlen($a);
                    $cb = strlen($b);
                    if($ca == $cb) return 0;
                    if($ca > $cb) return 1;
                    return -1;
                }
                usort($w, 'mycmp');

                $wc = 0; 
                foreach($w as $v) {
                    $c = strlen($v);
                    if($wc != $c) {
                        echo "<p>\n";
                        echo "<b>$c letter words</b><br>";
                    }
                    $wc = $c;
                    echo "$v  &nbsp; ";
                }
            }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be exceedingly lazy you could always solve fjsiem? by running your working code on fjsiema through fjsiemz.

If I'm reading your code right, you're finding the word list and only those with an f in them, then a j in them, then an s in them, then an i in them, then a e in them, then an m in them. So any and all words left which are 7 letters long, .{7} must match your criteria.